# javascript - how to break up a string every X amount of characters?

Tags: javascript

How do I break up a string every X amount of characters?  For example, I'd like to break up a very long string every 1000 characters, and the string could be completely random everytime.

`var string = <my text string that is thousands of characters long>`

Comment: Break up and do what with the parts? Wrap them in something? Add them to an array, or a variable?

Comment: no, just leave them as is, send them via POST, then I'll piece them together on the back-end.

Comment: You can `substring()` the string after you take the modulus of the `length` of the string and your amount `x` to determine the number of divisions.

Comment: What characters are possible? RegEx can bog down on large blocks of text.

Comment: any character is possible, and it may be something like hex values or HTML code, but I will URL encode the HTML code if that happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
'asdfasdfasdfasdf'.match(/.{3}|.{1,2}/g); // 'asd', 'fas', etc.
```

Replace 3 with 1000 of course.

Here's a contrived example: http://jsfiddle.net/ReRPz/1/

---

As a function:

```
function splitInto(str, len) {
    var regex = new RegExp('.{' + len + '}|.{1,' + Number(len-1) + '}', 'g');
    return str.match(regex );
}
```

That RegExp really only needs to be created once if you have a set number to split like 1000.

Comment: Don't use '.' for large blocks of text if you can avoid it. You'd be checking against an index of all but like 3 obscure whitespace characters 1000 times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```
function getParts(str, len)
{
    var res = [];
    ​while (str.length) {
        res.push(str.substring(0, len));
        str = str.substring(len);
    }
    return res;
}
var s = "qweasedzxcqweasdxzc12";
console.log(getParts(s, 10));
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var myString = "my text string that is thousands of characters long";
var myCurrentString = "";
var myBrokenUpString = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
    myCurrentString += myString.charAt(i);

    if(i % 1000 == 0) {
        myBrokenUpString.push(myCurrentString);
        myCurrentString = "";
    }

    if(i + 1 == myString.length) myBrokenUpString.push(myCurrentString);
}
```

*Please note that the above code is untested and may contain errors.*

You can then POST the array and piece it back together on the other end. The piecing-together-code would look something like this:

```
var myRestoredString = "";
for(var i = 0; i<myBrokenUpString.length; i++)  {
    myRestoredString += myBrokenUpString[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would use substring function on string

```
     str = //the given string
     arr = [];

     for(i=0;i<str.length;i+=1000)
     {
        s = i;
        // if the last string is less than 1000chars
        e = (str.length - i) > 1000 ? (i+1000) : (str.length - i); 
        arr.push = str.substring(s,e);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it recursively:

```
var string = "my text string that is thousands of characters long";

var arr = [];

function div( str, len ) {

    if( str.length < len )
        return arr.push(str);
    else
        arr.push(str.substring(0,len))

    div( str.substring(len), len );
}

div( string, 5 );

for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    document.write( arr[i] + "<br/>");  
}

/* output:

my te
xt st
ring 
that 
is th
ousan
ds of
char
acter
s lon
g


*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the idea from Joe Tuskan:

```
var str = 'asdfasdfasdfasdf';
var len = 3;
var regex = new RegExp(".{"+len+"}", "g");
var trail = str.length - (str.length % len);

var parts = str.match(regex);
parts.push(str.substring(trail));

document.write(parts.join('<br>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6aSHB/1/